# I need help to improve My C program code to solve a Differential equation using runge kutta 4th order method

Tags: c, runge-kutta

Please i need help with a c code. the code runs fyn actually, but i need it to do more. The program is a code to solve a system of differential equation using Runge Kutta 4th order method. To cut the long story short, all i need is a way for me to input the question from the interface, not inputed from inside the code. Please any help will be apprciated.

```
#define X0 1.0
#define Xn 2.0
#define STEPLEN 10
#define Y1 1 //initial condition for y1 at x=0
#define Y2 0 //initial condition for y2 at x=0
#‎include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double f1(double x,double y1,double y2)
{
    //a function to solve the functions 2 using x and y
    return(y2);
}
double f2(double x,double y1,double y2)
{
    //a function to solve the functions 1 using x and y
    return(x*log(x) - (2*y1)/(x*x) + (2*y2)/x);
}
main()
{
    double x,y1[STEPLEN],y2[STEPLEN];
    double xmid,k1[2],k2[2],k3[2],k4[2],h = (double)(Xn - X0)/STEPLEN;
    x = X0;
    y1[0]=Y1;
    y2[0]=Y2;
    int i;
    printf("This are the initial values. y1=%.10f y2=%.10f and h=%f\n\n", y1[0], y2[0],h);
    //printf("x\t|k1\t|k2\t|k3\t|k4\t|y\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<STEPLEN; i++){
        k1[0]=h * f1(x,y1[i],y2[i]);
        k1[1]=h * f2(x,y1[i],y2[i]);
        xmid = x + h/2.0;
        k2[0] = h * f1(xmid, y1[i] + k1[0] * 1/2.0, y2[i] + k1[1] * 1/2.0);
        k2[1] = h * f2(xmid, y1[i] + k1[0] * 1/2.0, y2[i] + k1[1] * 1/2.0);
        k3[0] = h * f1(xmid, y1[i] + k2[0] * 1/2.0, y2[i] + k2[1] * 1/2.0);
        k3[1] = h * f2(xmid, y1[i] + k2[0] * 1/2.0, y2[i] + k2[1] * 1/2.0);

        k4[0] = h * f1(x + h, y1[i] + k3[0] , y2[i] + k3[1]);
        k4[1] = h * f2(x + h, y1[i] + k3[0] , y2[i] + k3[1]);

        y1[i+1] = y1[i] + (k1[0] + 2*k2[0] + 2*k3[0] + k4[0])/6;

        y2[i+1] = y2[i] + (k1[1] + 2*k2[1] + 2*k3[1] + k4[1])/6;

        printf("When x=%f\n",x+h);
        printf("k1 for y1=%.10f\n",k1[0]);
        printf("k1 for y2=%.10f\n",k1[1]);
        printf("k2 for y1=%.10f\n",k2[0]);
        printf("k2 for y2=%.10f\n",k2[1]);
        printf("k3 for y1=%.10f\n",k3[0]);
        printf("k3 for y2=%.10f\n",k3[1]);
        printf("k4 for y1=%.10f\n",k4[0]);
        printf("k4 for y2=%.10f\n",k4[1]);
        printf("y1 when x is %f=\t%.10f\n",x+h,y1[i+1]);
        printf("y2 when x is %f=\t%.10f\n\n",x+h,y2[i+1]);
        // printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f \n",k1[0],k1[1],k2[0],k2[1],k3[0],k3[1],k4[0],k4[1],y1[i+1],y2[i+1]);
        x = x+h;

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Since you know how to use `printf`, you probably want to use [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Could simply do

```
    double X0, Xn;

    fputs("Enter X0\n", stdout);
    if (sscanf("%lf", &XO) != 1) Handle_EOForInputProblem();

    fputs("Enter Xn\n", stdout);
    if (sscanf("%lf", &Xn) != 1) Handle_EOForInputProblem();
    ...
```

Or create a helper function to prompt, handle user I/O issues, and read in the various `double`.

```
int Mayor_Read_Double(const char *prompt, double *dest) {
  char buffer[100];
  for (;;) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
      return -1;
    }
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    double number = strtod(buffer, &endptr);
    if (errno && number != 0.0) {
      fputs("Input out of range\n", stdout);
      continue;
      }
    if (buffer == endptr) {  // no conversion
      fputs("Invalid input\n", stdout);
      continue;
      }
    // Detect extra garbage
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++;
    if (*endptr) {
      fputs("Extra input\n", stdout);
      continue;
    }
    *dest = number;
    return 1;
  }
}

double X0, Xn;
if (Mayor_Read_Double("Enter X0\n", &X0) != 1) return 0;
if (Mayor_Read_Double("Enter Xn\n", &Xn) != 1) return 0;
  ...
```

Comment: Wow, am sorry, as u can see my code am not dat experienced or advanced, please can u explain further or possible put more comments in the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Mayor  Use first simply approach: Prompt for 1 variable like `X0`, scan in user input, check `scanf()` result to insure a `double` was read.  Do the same for `Xn`, `Y1`, `Y2`.